# How can i change the language of flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a dropdown item list of different languages and when user selects one of these app language should change. I don't know what logic to apply for changing language please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found translator's:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/translator
2. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_translate
3. https://pub.dev/packages/google_translator

By the plugins I writtend you have documentations but you also can go to youtube and look a tutorial about them.

Next time you can simple google what you want to have or go to pub.dev and writte in the search bar what you want.

I wish you a good day!

Comment: Two of the solutions proposed are based on the assumption that you want to use an automated translation service, which may not be what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the topic of internationalization: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization